# Setting instance field value inside method argument

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I encountered the following code while looking up an example of the Observer pattern. The 4th argument is a String, but I was wondering what happens there: Does it set the instance field `lastName` to the new `lastName` value and then return this `lastName`?

Is this form of shortening common practice?

```
 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  notifyListeners(this, "lastName", lastName, this.lastName = lastName);
}
```

Comment: Side note: `this.lastName` is not a "local variable," it's an "instance member" (specifically an "instance field"). A local variable would be one declared within the function. I've taken the liberty of editing the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That effectively does this:

```
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
  notifyListeners(this, "lastName", lastName, lastName);
}
```

E.g., first sets the instance member `lastName` to the argument `lastName` and then uses that same value again when calling the function.

I wouldn't say it's that common, though there are some idioms that use it (see below); in that specific case, there's no particularly good reason for doing it. The idea is that the "get from variable" operation reading `lastName` only needs to happen once, and then that value is assigned to `this.lastName` and also passed to the function. But the compiler and JVM are more than up to making sure clear code (within reason) is efficient, whereas they can't help people understand confusing code. :-)

As [jlordo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749753/jlordo) points out in the comments, there are some idioms where this kind of assign-and-use is common, for instance:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // ...
}
```

More rare when calling a function, but quite common in that kind of loop.

You also see it in compound assignment, e.g.:

```
x = y = z = foo();
```

...which calls `foo()`, sets `z` to the return value, then sets `y` to that same value, then sets `x` to that same value (without, obviously, repeating the call).

Comment: It's common in cases when reading lines from a file `while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {`

Comment: I'd go further and say that (in this case) there's no good reason for doing it. Hiding the assignment in the notification seems like obfuscation to me!

Comment: @jlordo: Very good point, I was focussing on the function call aspect. I've folded that into the answer, thanks.

Comment: I agree on the rareness when calling a method. In cases where I can't use a Guava Multimap and use a `HashMap<KeyType, Set<ValueType>>` instead I often do something like this for adding `Set<ValueType> set = map.get(key); if (set == null) { map.put(key, set = new HashSet<ValueType>()); } set.add(value);`